# Bulk generate Ethereum wallets

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm new to Ethereum and I'm working on a personal project. I want to create multiple Ethereum wallets at once with public/private keys, mnemonic, and QR codes. I found [this website](https://cointool.app/createWallet/eth) but it is online. Then I've tried [this](https://github.com/ryepdx/ethaddress.org) but it is not maintained anymore and there [is an error](https://github.com/ryepdx/ethaddress.org/issues/39). Is there any offline tool to generate multiple Ethereum wallets?

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum account is just a random 256-bit integer number that is generated with a cryptographically secure random number generator. To generate bunch of wallets you can simply do:

```
private_key = random(2**256)
```

Note that you **must not** use pseudorandom numbers, but true random number generator.

Then you can derive both Ethereum account public key and then address from this public key.

To understand better this please see the existing answers below:

- [How to make Ethereum account from a raw private key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82923/programmatically-getting-an-ethereum-address-for-a-raw-hex-private-key)
- [How to generate Ethereum addresses from command line](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82926/how-to-generate-a-new-ethereum-address-and-private-key-from-a-command-line)